# Does there exist complex function which is analytic in all $\Bbb{C}$ except for 5 points?

Tags: complex-analysis, analyticity, analytic-functions

> Does there exist complex function which is analytic in all $\Bbb{C}$ except for 5 points?

I would say it exist. $$f(z)=\frac{1}{z(z-1)(z-2)(z-3)(z-4)}$$ But how should I prove that it is analytic everywhere except for $z=0,1,2,3,4$?

Comment: The quotient of two analytic functions $f/g$ is analytic where $g$ is not zero.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ordinary quotient rule and product rule show that this is differentiable everywhere except at those five points. If "analytic" is taken to mean locally equal to the limit of its Taylor series, then a standard theorem says it's analytic at each point in $\mathbb C$ at which it's differentiable everywhere in some open neighborhood of that point.